# how to plot 3D mesh to depth map

Tags: python, matplotlib, mesh

I have a 3d triangle mesh

```
from torch_geometric.data import Data
```

want to plot it as depth map from top view, so the pixel value of (x,y) equals depth value.

there is a piece of code to plot, but I don't know how to calculate z value for each pair of (x,y)

```
plt.subplot()
x = data.x[:,1]
y = data.x[:,0]
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
plt.pcolor(data.x[:,1], data.x[:,0], data.x[:,2] * 255, cmap='RdBu', vmin=0, vmax=255)
```

Comment: I don't know either. You have to provide much more information.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [tripcolor](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tripcolor.html).

Simply cut off the `z`-component from your data and use `z` as the value in your plot:

```py
tpc = ax1.tripcolor(triang, z, shading='flat')
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, it's close, but each triangle has the same color. maybe i should try zdepth of  blender

Comment: @Lamp It doesn't have to have the same color.